# alert_profit & alert_loss doesn't work on strategy.entry function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to have an specific alert message once a position is opened or closed, I first tried this way:

```
if condition
    strategy.entry(id="sell", direction=strategy.short, comment = "GoShort", alert_message = "Open Long)
```

But it didn't give the message "Open Long" once the alert was triggered. Than I solved the problem like this:

```
//@version=5
strategy(blablabla)

if condition
    strategy.entry(id="sell", direction=strategy.short, comment = "GoShort")
    alert("Open Long")
```

But now I can not find a solution for the Take Profit and Stop Loss using strategy.exit like this:

```
//@version=5
strategy(blablabla)

strategy.exit(id = "exitShort", from_entry = "sell", qty_percent = 100,
              limit = x1, stop = x2, comment_profit="TPShort", comment_loss="SLShort",
              alert_profit = "TAKE PROFIT", alert_loss = "STOP LOSS")
```

The comments are perfectly triggered on the chart (SLShort/TPShort)code runs perfectly, but the alert messages not. When creating the alert, if I:

- Choose alert() function calls only, no alerts are triggered from strategy.exit
- Choose alert() and order fills, I get a message but with the text typed on the Creating Alert Dialog Box
- Choose alert() and order fils, removing all of the content of the textbox "message" on the Creating Alert Dialog Box, I get the alert but with no content

Can you guys please give a hand?

Maybe I am misunderstanding how alert_message, alert_profit and alert_loss works

PS: Sorry for the "blablabla" on strategy(), the idea was to write as less as possible rsrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `alert_message`, `alert_profit`, `alert_loss` arguments.

In order for this to work, when you create your alert, you must use the `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}` alert message placeholder in the message text box.

[image]

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot, it was so simple but I just didn´t realize that. Maybe I am too noob but I was not able to link this procedures with the explanation of "alert_message" on the description of strategy.entry, strategy.close and strategy.exit functions. BTW, thanks again!